# Redirect one domain and every sub-page to a different domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect

I have read numerous people with this question and have tried numerous strategies.  However, I am still unable to redirect all sub-pages for peaceandtruth.com over to oldmankit.com, which is what I want.  My situation may be a little confused because I am using one shared hosting account with an add-on domain.  oldmankit.com is the addon domain.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^peaceandtruth\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://oldmankit.com [R=301,L]
```

If you go to http://peaceandtruth.com/me/, you will see that it is not redirecting.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^peaceandtruth\.com$ [NC]
```

This means "If HTTP_HOST is **NOT** *peaceandtruth.com*". 
Lose the exclamation mark for a positive match.

Comment: Thank you for solving this so simply.